# Inverse Clipping Mask in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, mask

I have this text on a white bar in Illustrator, and I would like to make that part of the white bar transparent instead of what it currently is - the same color as the background.

I tried doing the clipping mask, but it does the opposite, it gets rid of the white bar and makes the text white

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

[image]

when I then try to make a compound path, the 2015 converts fine, but there is another compound path that I try to do this to and it does not work, and it also distorts some of the letters:

[image]

Comment: Assuming this artwork is made up of actual Illustrator vector objects and not a placed image (pixel-based), delete the blue box and the white box. And thus you get "transparent" background. If the artwork is not native Illustrator objects, then I'd suggest recreating the artwork. You would then have total control over what is and isn't in the final art.

Comment: Did you try Ryan's method in the linked duplicate?

Comment: @JohnB yes I did. I tried both methods from the answers, but it still distorts the logo paths... if you look at the E, it should not be that way. What's weird is that when the logo is larger and I try this it works, but still has minimal changes

Comment: It's difficult to tell just from a screenshot where things might be going wrong. If you upload an .ai file to Dropbox, I'd be happy to take a look

Comment: @JohnB I uploaded it here, let me know if this is OK - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6zlUNco7sq9SGtoczZmeHNKZUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JohnB although I spoke to the company that will be screen printing this stuff, and they said the screen print templates are composed of black-white so I can accomplish what I want, but now I am just curious for completeness sake

Comment: @Adjit using your file, I had no problems following Vicki's solution. I selected the ORIGINAL layer and a rectangle behind it then used _Object > Compound Path > Make_ to get this result http://i.stack.imgur.com/SdNiW.png

Comment: @JohnB Ok, I think I see what I was doing wrong... The logo was above the rectangle in layer order. I changed it up and it seems to have done the trick. What is the reason the text seemed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method won't allow your text to be edited later, but if that's not a problem for you, try using a Compound Path:

1. Select your text, go to **Type > Create Outlines**
   [image]
   [image]
2. Select your new text shape and your rectangle, and go to **Object > Compound Path > Make**

[image]

Comment: Please see my edits to the question. I tried this, but it did not work as expected